# Como faço para exibir o teclado usando cordova ou phonegap?

Tags: javascript, android, apache-cordova, teclado

Estou usando cordova/phonegap e gostaria de saber: Como faço para exibir o teclado (no SO android) assim que o usuário entrar, em uma pagina que só possui um campo texto?

Answer (score 2):

Parece que por guidelines de usabilidade, alguns SOs trazem restriçao para invocação automatica de teclado. Porém voce pode tentar pelo duas "soluções de contorno":

- chamar a função prompt()
- Chamar a função .focus() de dentro de uma chamada programatica de um handler de evento .click()

Mais detalhes você pode ler aqui nestas outras discussões do SO sobre o mesmo tema:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837543/show-virtual-keyboard-on-mobile-phones-in-javascript
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15457783/can-i-trigger-android-soft-keyboard-to-open-via-javascript-without-phonegap